# JavaScript Regex unlimited substitution variables

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to replicate some of the Regex sites that allows you to return a new string based on the pattern groups.

**ie:**

- https://regex101.com/
- https://regexr.com/
- https://www.regextester.com/

I was trying to use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function but I don't get how to "customize" its second parameter.

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) its receives a replacement function that accepts parameters as pattern groups:

```js
const pattern = new RegExp(/(Test) ([0-9])/, "g")
const str = "Test 1\nTest 2"
function replacer(match, g1, g2, offset, string) {
    // ...
}
const output = str.replace(pattern, replacer);
```

Here we have two matches:

1. `g1` = ["Test", "Test"]
2. `g2` = ["1", "2"]

But in the previous sites there are not a fixed number of groups but a lot of them, according to the user input. I thought something like this:

```js
const userInput = "Test 1\nTest 2\nTest3";
const patternInput = "(Test) ([0-9)";
const substitutionInput = "";
let output = "";

const pattern = new RegExp(patternInput, "g");
const groups = patternInput.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
const dynamicVariables = Object.keys(groups).map(n => "g"+n);
const dynamicReplacer = value => `function(match, ${[...dynamicVariables]}, offset, string) { return ${value}; }`;
const dynamicFn = dynamicReplacer(substitutionInput);
output = userInput.replace(pattern, eval(dynamicFn));
```

**Edit 1:**

The form would look like:

```html
<textarea id="userInput" />
<input id="patternInput" />
<textarea id="substitutionInput" />
<textarea id="output"  readOnly />
```

Well, this doesn't work at all. But I think demonstrates what I need to achieve. Any ideas how to achieve this? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly would be the desired output from that example?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I'm not asking about the way the initial strings get set, I'm asking about what sort of output you want from `const userInput = "Test 1\nTest 2\nTest3";
const patternInput = "(Test) ([0-9)";
const substitutionInput = "";`. Do you want all full matches to be replaced with the empty string, or all capture groups replaced with the empty string, or..?

Comment: Could you reply? Hard to help without understanding the expected logic

Comment: I am sorry, I left work place and I don&#39;t have a PC around. But what I want is to replicate the mentioned sites where the substitution input is what is replaced by the captured groups defined in the pattern. I will try to expand this.

Comment: Do you mean you want the replacement to be all capture groups concatenated together? Eg `Test1Test2Test3`?

Comment: Best to [stick around to clarify](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) your question after asking, rather than leave

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write some expression similar to,

```
^Test\s*([0-9]+)\s*^Test\s*([0-9]+)\s*^Test\s*([0-9]+)\s*
```

not sure though.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WyaugJ/1/)